# Onsen UI Vue swipeable Tabbar Doesn't work

Tags: javascript, cordova, vue.js, vuejs2, onsen-ui

i used this template to start

https://github.com/OnsenUI/vue-cordova-webpack

and then i add a tabbar its ok but the swipeable attribute doesn't work
when i run the code i can click tabs and its work but swipe doesn't work

i can swipe in the onsen ui demo so my browser is ok

here is my Tabbar component

```
<template>
  <v-ons-page>
    <v-ons-toolbar>
      <div class="center">{{ title }}</div>
    </v-ons-toolbar>

    <v-ons-tabbar
      swipeable position="auto"
      :tabs="tabs"
      :visible="true"
      :index.sync="activeIndex"
    >
    </v-ons-tabbar>
  </v-ons-page>
</template>


<script>
import Dashboard from './components/dashboard.vue';
import Diary from './components/diary.vue';

export default {
  data () {
    return {
      activeIndex: 0,
      tabs: [
        {
          label: 'dash',
          page: Dashboard,
          icon: this.md() ? null : 'ion-ios-settings',
          key: "Dashboard"
        },
        {
          label: 'diar',
          page: Diary,
          icon: this.md() ? null : 'ion-ios-settings',
          key: "Diary"
        }
      ]
    };
  },
  methods: {
    md() {
      return this.$ons.platform.isAndroid();
    }
  },
  computed: {
    title() {
      return this.tabs[this.activeIndex].label;
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when i putt attr animation on tabbar object
it fix the problem

```
 <v-ons-tabbar
   position="auto"
   animation="fade"
   swipeable 
  :tabs="tabs"
  :visible="true"
  :index.sync="activeIndex"
>
</v-ons-tabbar>
```

Fran Dios in other community help me to do this so i give the reward

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are using at least `onsenui@2.6.0` and `vue-onsenui@2.2.0`. Changelog [here](https://github.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md). If possible, just update to the latest version. Check `package.json` file and change the version numbers or, if you are using [yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/en/), simply run `yarn upgrade onsenui vue-onsenui`.